# Modifying Timer in a Loop [Excel/VBA]

Tags: excel, vba, timer

I am working with a loop that is switching worksheets every 30 seconds. After the worksheet loops through 300 times, I need it to call a macro; however, the additional macro takes 5 minutes to run.

I need to be able to call the macro and adjust the timer to account for the 5 minute interval. I believe that the macro is crashing because it does not know how to get back to the proper sheet that should be loaded as so much time has passed. How can I increase the amount of time that is needed for the additional macro? Here is a block of the code that I am working with:

```vb
For j = 1 To Loops 'This counts the number of loops executed
    For i = 1 To 5 'There are 5 pages in the worksheet
        Worksheets(i).Select 'Select the next worksheet

        x = Timer
        While Timer - x < Pause 'This does the pausing
            DoEvents
        Wend
         
        If i = 1 And j = 300 Then Call Refresh 'When this completes, the macro crashes. Refresh is the name of the Macro.
```

I have tried adding in additional `If Then` statements to try updating and then returning the `Timer` count from 5 to 300 and then back to 5, but get error 91 runtime errors. These are the additional `If Then` Statements that I added. `If i = 2 And j = 1 Then Pause = 300 'This would set the pause timer for this event to 5 minutes` and `If i = 3 And j = 1 Then Pause = 5 'This should reset the timer back to 5 seconds`

Comment: `it does not know how to get back to the proper sheet that should be loaded as so much time has passed` - no, it's much more likely that you have messed something up in that `Refresh`. Then again, Excel can and does crash inexplicably when left to run macros unattended for noticeable periods of time. `DoEvents` will exacerbate it.

Comment: @Gserg My apologies, Refresh is actually the name of the macro being called. The Macro is tied to a button on page 2 of the worksheet, it will pull data from Oracle E-business Suite and update 4 sheets in the workbook with data.  So, the refresh macro is stopping on the 4th worksheet and crashes without going back to worksheet 3 like it should be doing. I will edit the original code to add in that note.

Comment: `switching worksheets every 30 seconds` Do you have to swich activesheet? In most case, `Select` and `Activate` should be avoided.
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10717999#10717999)

Comment: @taller I am looking at that page. I am considering if there is a better way to handle calling the next sheet as active, and this does give me ideas. The purpose of this code is to run a Kiosk. Excel will be running displaying data and then once per day, it will call the refresh to load new data from EBS.

Comment: This [Excel Clock](https://davetallett26.github.io/excelclock.html) works in a different way. I have never seen it crash but have never run it all day.